# Ansible Playbook - Symbolic links for directories not working as expected

Tags: ansible

I am currently trying to work on migrating my dotfiles setup from a Shell Script to an Ansible Playbook. I have gotten most of the processes migrated over...aside from the (Soft) Symbolic Links.

The general file structure of the repository looks like this:

- setup.sh
- playbook.yaml
- dotfiles/

  - zsh/

    - ...
  - nvim/

    - ...

With the shell script, I loop inside the dotfiles and create a Symlink for each directory. e.g.

```bash
#ln -s "$SCRIPT_DIR/dotfiles/$dir" "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"

ln -s "<script_dir>/dotfiles/zsh" "/home/louis/.dotfiles-configs"
```

That would result in the zsh directory and the contents from my git repo to be symlink'd into the /home/louis/.dotfiles-configs directory

With the Ansible Playbook, I did the same logic but using this (a very shortened version):

```yaml
- name: Dotfiles Playbook setup - Work
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true

  vars:
    # playbook_dir - for the location of Ansible playbook
    XDG_CONFIG_HOME: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'HOME') }}/.dotfiles-configs"
    work_dotfiles:
      - nvim
      - zsh

  tasks:
    - name: Symlinks - Work setup
      ansible.builtin.file:
        src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/dotfiles/{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ XDG_CONFIG_HOME }}"
        state: link
        force: no
      loop: "{{ work_dotfiles }}"
```

By logic with the Shell Script, it should do the same thing - instead, it symlink'd the **contents** of the directory into /home/louis/.dotfiles-config instead of the directory itself.

Have I done something wrong here? Any explanation or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In short => `dest: "{{ XDG_CONFIG_HOME }}/{{ item }}"`

Comment: Thanks very much @Zeitounator! I was following the processes I did on my shell script and that definitely did not cross my mind. Much appreciated!

Comment: We don't put answers in questions on this site. If you want to answer the question, use the Your Answer box below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Zeitounator for the answer!

`dest: "{{ XDG_CONFIG_HOME }}/{{ item }}"`